# Having trouble with || and &&

Tags: java

I am new to programming and wanted to make a dice rolling programm in Java for execise.
The code is the following:

```
import java.math.*;
public class Dices {
public static int dice1=0;
    public static int dice2=0;
    public static int x;
    public static void main(String args[]){
    do {
        x++;
        dice1=(int) (Math.random()*6+1);
        dice2=(int) (Math.random()*6+1);
        System.out.println(dice1+", "+dice2);
    } while(dice1 !=1 || dice2 !=1);
    System.out.println("Finalthrow: "+dice1+", "+dice2);
    System.out.println("Snake-Eyes after "+x+" tries.");
    }
}
```

This way it works fine, but in my opinion there is something wrong with the code. In the `while` condition should actually be. But if I use `&&` it stops as soon as it rolls a 1 on the first dice. I thought `&&` means "AND" and  `||` means "OR". So actually it should behave exactly the other way around, or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: I though "||" means "OR" and "&&" means "AND". But in my code it behaves exactly the other way around.

Comment: `while(dice1 !=1 || dice2 !=1) => while(!(dice1 == 1 && dice2 ==1)) => loop until both of the dice are not showing one` Look at De Morgan's law.

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to go back and learn a bit more about logics ;-)
 Thx for the fast replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some understanding about [Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) could help here. The law says (sorry for the weird syntax, but I think the message is clear) that :

```
(!P) OR (!Q) == !(P AND Q)
(!P) AND (!Q) == !(P OR Q)
```

So when you use **`||` (OR)** in your condition

```
while(dice1 !=1 || dice2 !=1)
```

is exactly the same as

```
while(!(dice1 == 1 && dice2 == 1))
```

so it will looop until both dice are `1`.

*On the other hand, if you use* **`&&` (AND)**:

```
while(dice1 !=1 && dice2 !=1)
```

it's the same as

```
while(!(dice1 == 1 || dice2 == 1))
```

so it means that it will loop until *one or two* of the dice is/are `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
&& means and
|| means or
```

So (dice1 != 1 || dice2 != 1) means continue the loop while dice1 is not 1 or dice 2 is not 1.

So (dice1 != 1 && dice2 != 1) means continue the loop while dice1 is not 1 and dice 2 is not 1.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. You want the loop to end when `dice1 == 1` and `dice2 == 1`. So it must loop until that is true, or until its opposite is false. The opposite of `dice1 == 1 && dice2 == 1` is `!(dice1 == 1 && dice2 == 1)` which is equivalent to `dice1 != 1 || dice2 != 1`.

Think of it this way: if `dice1 != 1`, keep looping. Also, if `dice2 != 1`, keep looping. So if either is true, keep looping. And to test if *either* is true, regardless of if *both* are true, use `||`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is wright. You're saying with `dice1 !=1 && dice2 !=1` that repeat the loopuntil BOTH of the dices are NOT 1. But when one dice rolls a 1 the condition is false and the loop escapes. Try it with a truth table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a truth table.

[image]

What can we conclude from this? If you want your loop to continue while ***either* `A` or `B` are different from `1`** (or, as De Morgan's laws say: *until both of them are equal to `1`*) then you can narrow it down to these values:

[image]

Since we need to find the operator that allows us to continue the loop (aka: the condition is `true`), we take the column that returns `true` for all 3 different kinds of inputs, which is `A || B`.

Note that `A && B` and `A || B` refer to the result of `A != 1` and `B != 1`, not the actual input.